# Is there a way to add comments to powershell cmdlet parameter sets

Tags: powershell

Suppose that I have a cmdlet that has several (more than 3) parameter sets.  It may be complicated for the user to figure out which one they should use for their use case.  Is there anyway to document the parameter sets so that the when using **Get-Help** cmdlet, the documentation shows up?

For example:

```
PS C:\> get-help Do-Stuff

NAME
    Do-Stuff

SYNTAX
    Do-Stuff -My [-P1 <string>] [-P2 <string>] [-P3 <string>]

    ->Use when doing my stuff.<-

    Do-Stuff -Your [-P1 <string>] [-P4 <string>] [-P5 <string>]

    ->Use when doing your stuff.<-

    Do-Stuff -Their <string> [-P2 <string>] [-P4 <string>] [-P6 <string>]

    ->Use when doing their stuff.<-

PARAMETERS
    . . .
```

That is, how do I get the stuff between the `->` arrows `<-` to show up?

Comment: Use [comment-based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help) and add examples. The examples won't appear between the syntax descriptions but that's not any different from standard cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

Bill_Stewart has put you on the right track. You can also look at cmdlets on your system for how help was implemented there.

Make a copy of ...
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
 ... to peer at what's there

You can use the PowerShell_ISE or VSCode to view those items not obfuscated.
You can use tools to look at PowerShell help files and even build help files for your cmdlets/modules/Functions efforts.

Examples:

PowerShell Cmdlet Help Editor a WPF tool to edit help content for PowerShell modules

```
https://github.com/Crypt32/PsCmdletHelpEditor
```

Or you can get Sapien's 'PS Cmdlet Help Editor' or their 'PowerShell HelpWriter'.

There are built-in ways to look at source code of functions and look at what's there as examples as well.

```
Get-Command -CommandType Function
# Use the output to review function content
${function:Write-VolumeCache} | clip.exe
```

Or this way

```
Get-Command -Name 'Format-Hex' -CommandType Function `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Definition' `
| clip.exe
```

There are other ways to get to view source code of modules / cmdlets /functions.

You of course can write a function to add to your $profile to look at this kind of thing on the fly.

Update as per my comment to the OP. This is what Bill_Stewart and I were pointing you to.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx#HelpMessage

```
Example:


Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="secure")]
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = "Enter the title for the input box. No more than 25 characters.",
        ParameterSetName="plain")]        

        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({$_.length -le 25})]
        [string]$Title = "User Input",

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="secure")]        
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = "Enter a prompt. No more than 50 characters.",ParameterSetName="plain")]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({$_.length -le 50})]
        [string]$Prompt = "Please enter a value:",

        [Parameter(HelpMessage = "Use to mask the entry and return a secure string.",
        ParameterSetName="secure")]
        [switch]$AsSecureString
    )
```

The comment of looking at other the example pointers, would have shown this sort of thing as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about whether it's possible to add comments to parameter sets.  You are basically telling me "look at examples".  I haven't seen any examples of this.

Comment: Both Bill_Stewart and I are giving you the same guidance. But you are asking to show you an example, when we are pointing you to where you can see examples. Any example we'd put here would also be in the avenues we pointed you to. It's called the Parameter HelpMessage Attribute. This is also detailed here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx#HelpMessage. See my update to assist you.